# Subtotal for ATTR function

Tags: tableau-api, attr, cumulative-sum, subtotal

I am trying to create a subtotal row after running total calculation. However, subtotal calculation doesn't seem correct.

I have two calculation fields. First one is to calculate running total of count of distinct emails.

[image]

Second calculation field is to use running total multiply by another field "charge quarterly".
[image]

In my final output, i also segment by cost center ID and licensing role ID. Number looks correct for "calculation 2" calculate field and non-subtotal total charges field. However, subtotal calculation for total charges field doesn't look correct. In some cases, subtotal doesn't even show up.

[image]

Can someone help me on how to add correct subtotal here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the subtotal provided by tableau

**Tab**

```
-> Analysis -> Totals -> Add all subtotals
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! That was exactly what I did but it seems like to subtotal is not correct